# SilverStripe adjust TinyMCE width / height

Tags: php, silverstripe

How to adjust `HTMLFieldEditor` (ie TinyMCE) width / height in SS 3.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width is controlled by css. The height can be changes with `setRows()` method:

```
$field = HTMLEditorField::create('Summary')->setRows(5);
```